# Synchronize code inside a servlet filter

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, servlet-filters, synchronized

I am having a servlet filter and within that I need to make some code as thread safe.

I am giving the abstract code:

```
doFilter() {
{
......
if (condition1) {
TestClass testObj = StaticTestClass.getTestObj();
testObj = testObj.setTestStr(testObj.getTestStr() + "Success");
StaticTestClass.setTestObj(testObj);
}
.....
}
```

I want to make it thread safe. condition1 will be true very rarely and hence there will be negligible performance hit because of synchronization. So I can do any of the following:

```
doFilter() {
{
......
if (condition1) {
TestClass testObj = StaticTestClass.getTestObj();
synchronized(this) {
testObj = testObj.setTestStr(testObj.getTestStr() + "Success");
StaticTestClass.setTestObj(testObj);
}}
......
}
```

or

```
doFilter() {
{
......
if (condition1) {
TestClass testObj = StaticTestClass.getTestObj();
synchronized(testObj) {
testObj = testObj.setTestStr(testObj.getTestStr() + "Success");
StaticTestClass.setTestObj(testObj);
}}
......
}
```

As per my understanding, conceptually the second one is more accurate as it is taking the lock of testObj. But the first one will also be correct as there will be only one instance of a servlet filter in the container.

Please let me know if anyone is having different opinion.

Comment: what is changing `condition1`?

Comment: Is `condition1` an attribute from `this`?

Comment: No, condition1 is not from this. StaticTestClass.getTestObj() is changing.

Comment: `StaticTestClass.getTestObj` is changing `condition1`?

Comment: no, condition1 is independent of StaticTestClass.getTestObj()

Comment: is `testObj` read or modified elsewhere?

Comment: answered preemptively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: The second option is the more correct of the two, because the goal of the synchronized statements is to access `testObj`, not `this`.

If at some point in the future you need to implement new features in your app and add other accesses to `testObj`, you will have to make that synchronization on `testObj`, and **not** on `this`.  So you might as well make it so from the start.